# VS2015 Asp.Net Web App + IE11 + AdBlock Plus hangs

Tags: c#, asp.net

As a quick intro, I have lots of C# experience, but ZERO web dev experience, I'm a desktop/backend guy. I'm just trying to put together a quick personal project.

I want to create a quick website for said project, I did it as follows:

VS2015 Latest Updates | New Project | ASP.Net Web Application | MVC | No Authentication, No Web Forms, No Web API

Windows 7 Professional, all latest patches + IE11 + Latest version of AdBlock Plus

I made ZERO changes to the project, I just created it and ran it inside the debugger to see the starting point. IE + AdBlock Plus causes the CPU to go to 13% and the website hangs. If I disable AdBlock Plus, it works fine.

Obviously, AdBlock plus is messing with the site somehow... is there any way to get the project to work with my configuration? No, I don't want to use Chrome or disable AdBlock plus. Just my personal preferences at this time.

Any way to see what's causing the hang or fix it?

EDIT: I did notice that there were 10 Nuget updates to the stock project, so I installed all those... same thing. 13% CPU + web site hang.

EDIT #2:

I tried doing this:

```
1) disable adblock plus
2) launch site in IE11
3) Hit F12
4) Start Profiler
5) Turn On Adblock Plus
6) Click on page to start CPU 13% / hang behavior
7) View Profiler Results
```

Like I said, I'm not a web dev, so I'm guessing on here... but the profiler said all the time was on a DOM event change status and it looks like its getting in some kind of GC loop or something.

Comment: Add http://localhost as exception to AdBlock

Comment: @Max, that'll fix the local issue, but it isn't going to fix the problem when the app is deployed to IIS.